# Strange Angularjs math

Tags: javascript, angularjs, watch

I am learning Angularjs. I am trying to do some simple math, just to get the feel for Angular. I have two input fields, I want to put numbers in the those and then see the added total in a third field. As it is, the math gets all weird...some numbers it adds fine, other times it doesn't add at all, and other times the total is a random incorrect number. Any ideas? I feel like I am doing the $watch method wrong. Is there some way to watch two variables with one $watch?

HTML -

```
<td><input class="form-control" name="account"placeholder="Account"></td>
                <td><input class="form-control" name="incomeone" ng-model="funding.startingEstimate"></td>
                <td class="warning"></td>
                <td>{{funding.startingEstimate}}</td>
                <td class="warning">$500</td>
                <td class="warning">50%</td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
              <td><input class="form-control" value=""name="account"placeholder="Account"></td>
                <td><input class="form-control" name="incometwo" ng-model="funding2.startingEstimate"></td>
                <td class="warning"></td>
                <td>{{funding2.startingEstimate}}</td>
                <td class="warning">$500</td>
                <td class="warning">50%</td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
              <td><input class="form-control" placeholder="Account" ng-model="r.account"></td>
                <td><input class="form-control" name="incometwo" placeholder="Budgeted"></td>
                <td class="warning"></td>
                <td></td>
                <td class="warning">{{funding.needed}}</td>
                <td class="warning">50%</td>
              </tr>
```

Javascript

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);

function TodoCtrl($scope) {
 $scope.funding = { startingEstimate: 0 };
 $scope.funding2 = { startingEstimate: 0 };
computeNeeded = function(funding, funding2) {
$scope.funding.needed = $scope.funding.startingEstimate|0 + $scope.funding2.startingEstimate|0;
};
$scope.$watch('funding.startingEstimate', computeNeeded);
$scope.$watch('funding2.startingEstimate', computeNeeded);
    }
```

Comment: You seem to think `|` is of greater precedence than `+`. It's not. )

Comment: you should be able to make this work without having anything in the controller, if you wanted to. `<td>{{(funding.startingEstimate|0) + (funding2.startingEstimate|0)}}</td>`

Comment: @KevinB Mind if I add this to the answer? )

Comment: Sure. I was curious though... could he also do `{{computeNeeded()}}` so that he could still do more advanced calculations if he wanted? i'm an angularjs noob. :) (hah, interesting typo. `{{computerNeeded()}}`)

Comment: If `computeNeeded` has been defined on `scope`, why not? For globals, not so sure, though.

Comment: Ah, yeah of course it would have to be on the scope, i'd think.

Comment: @raina77ow: for variables in the root scope, it's possible to use `$root.computeNeeded()` in the template

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This expression...

```
$scope.funding.startingEstimate|0 + $scope.funding2.startingEstimate|0
```

... actually is processed as this (because precedence of `+` operator is [**greater**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Operator_Precedence) than of `|` one):

```
$scope.funding.startingEstimate|(0 + $scope.funding2.startingEstimate)|0
```

... that is, essentially, binary ORing two `estimates`. And results of `binary OR` can look really weird sometimes. )

Add parens to establish the order of operations you actually wanted, like this:

```
($scope.funding.startingEstimate|0) + ($scope.funding2.startingEstimate|0)
```

---

And, as @KevinB correctly noticed, you can just right this into an expression within the template:

```
<td>{{(funding.startingEstimate|0) + (funding2.startingEstimate|0)}}</td>
```

Ordering the operations correctly matters here as well, of course.

Comment: Awesome! Ah just a matter of putting them in (). That was driving me crazy. I thought |0 would convert a numerical string into a int. I tried using parseInt() in a few places too without avail. Thank you much!